# How to run emacs function from the shell

Tags: command-line-arguments

I would like to:

1. run an emacs function from the shell
2. in a standard emacs session (configured as if it was run in an interactive session)
3. with a certain file in the active buffer

So I would like to do something like:

```
emacs --function org-beamer-export-to-pdf --file my-presentation.org
```

Bonus points if I can run it with the emacsclient, connecting to an already running emacs server.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do what you want. If you don't have the file open, you may need to replace the `switch-to-buffer` function to something that opens the file.

```
emacsclient -e '(progn (switch-to-buffer "my-presentation.org") (org-beamer-export-to-pdf))'
```

Comment: Great, I had to use `find-file` instead of `switch-to-buffer`

Comment: Should I do somethings as follows: `emacsclient -e '(progn (switch-to-buffer "foo.py"))'`

Comment: @alper Would that be identical to `emacsclient foo.py`?

Comment: @AstroFloyd Yes sir it will