# run emacs function in the shell with parameter

Tags: org-mode, org-export, shell, functions

Since there is parameter I need to use, so I will not use single quote as the [question's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/26915/how-to-run-emacs-function-from-the-shell)

First, I try

```
emacsclient -q --eval (progn (find-file "ORG/${UN}.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))
```

> zsh: bad pattern: (progn (find-file ORG/Austin.org)
>   (org-latex-export-to-pdf))

Then,

```
emacsclient -q --eval "(progn (find-file "ORG/${UN}.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))"
```

I get the error again

> *ERROR*: Symbol’s value as variable is void: ORG/Austin\.org

The question is how to give the parameters.

**Update**

I still get error after backslash the period

```
emacsclient -q --eval "(progn (find-file "ORG/${UN}\.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))"
```

> *ERROR*: Symbol’s value as variable is void: ORG/Austin\.org

Comment: This is a zsh question and nothing to do with org-mode, org-export etc.  . Have you tried to backslash the inner apostrophs ?

Comment: @politza Still get error after backslash the period
`emacsclient -q --eval "(progn (find-file "ORG/${UN}\.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))"`


`*ERROR*: Symbol’s value as variable is void: ORG/Austin\.org`

Comment: `...(find-file \"ORG/${UN}\.org\")...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either

```
emacsclient -q --eval "(progn (find-file \"ORG/${UN}.org\") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))"
```

or

```
emacsclient -q --eval '(progn (find-file "ORG/'"${UN}"'.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))'
```

The problem that needs to be solved is to give the string `"ORG/Austin.org"` rather than the symbol `ORG/Austin.org` to emacs.

Comment: What should I do to only open the file instead of piping it into pdf?

Comment: @alper Can you expand your question - I don't understand what you are asking? The emacs lisp code is a `progn` which says "do a sequence of things". Inside that the sequence is `find-file` to open the file and `org-latex-export-to=pdf`. If all you want is to open the file then remove the `(org-latex-export-to-pdf)` but this seems overkill! Perhaps you should  start a new question?

Answer (score 0):

```
emacs --batch foo.org -f org-latex-export-to-pdf
```

- `--batch`: Run Emacs in batch mode
- `foo.org`: Open `foo.org` and set it as current buffer (`org.el` is loaded by the way)
- `-f org-latex-export-to-pdf`: Then call `org-latex-export-to-pdf` to export the current buffer to pdf

---

As your tries

```
emacsclient -q --eval (progn (find-file "ORG/${UN}.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))
```

you need quote your expression for shell since it contains white spaces.

```
emacsclient -q --eval "(progn (find-file "ORG/${UN}.org") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))"
```

you need escape the inner `"` because you are using `"` outside. You can refer to [@icarus's answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28252/3889), I think it's correct. However, instead of writing Lisp in your shell, you can just make a function in Emacs and call it using `emacsclient` from command line, for example,

```
(defun my-org-latex-export-to-pdf ()
  ...)

$ emacsclient --eval '(my-org-latex-export-to-pdf)'
```

In Emacs Lisp, you can use `getenv` to access value of environment variable if you need to.

Answer (score -1):

Use eval solve this question.

```
 eval "emacsclient -q --eval '(progn (find-file \"ORG/$UN.org\") (org-latex-export-to-pdf))'"
```

Comment: eval is a very useful and powerful feature of the shell, but is almost certainly the wrong tool for this. You just need to get the quotes correct,